# Regular expression to match weight (lbs) inside different html tags

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match

I have an HTML file  that contains products information including their weights. I am trying to get the weights(any numbers that precede lbs).  occasionally there are space between lbs and the weight number.
 I came up with the regex:
`preg_match(">[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)(.*?)lbs/i",fgets($file),$matches);` but this is returning everything between the first '>' and 'lbs', it is not practical since there are a lot of tags involved. so what I am trying to accomplish is to get only the number between the character '>' that directly precedes the weight and the characters 'lbs' that follows the weight ignoring the space between.

so in the example below, I want to get 0.94,0.12,0.94. Any help is appreciated.

```
<td width="513" valign="top">0.94 lbs
<td width="513" valign="top">0.12lbs
<td width="513" valign="top">0.94LBS
<td width="513" valign="top">penguin lover
```

Noticee that the tags '`<td width="513" valign="top">`' precedes other characters besides the weight.

Any thoughts, help will be appreciated.

Comment: Obligatory SO question link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/758446

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
/(?<=>)[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9][0-9]?)(?=\s*lbs)/i
```

This uses a lookahead and a lookbehind such that the only thing matched is the decimal number.

**Explanation:**

`(?<=>)` Lookbehind to check for a `>` -- `(?<=xxx)` means look behind for `xxx`

`[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9][0-9]?)` Your unchanged decimal regex using a non-capturing group `(?:xxx)`

`(?=\s*lbs)` Lookahead for 0-many whitespace characters followed by `lbs`

Note that you can replace each `[0-9]` with `\d` if you want, they are equivalent.

**Example code:**

```
$str = '<td width="513" valign="top">0.94 lbs
        <td width="513" valign="top">0.12lbs
        <td width="513" valign="top">0.94LBS
        <td width="513" valign="top">penguin lover';

preg_match_all("/(?<=>)[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9][0-9]?)(?=\s*lbs)/i",$str,$matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

**Output:**

```
 Array ( [0] => 0.94 [1] => 0.12 [2] => 0.94 )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all('/[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)(?=\s*lbs)/i', $html, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Regular expression:

```
[0-9]+         any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more times)
(?:            group, but do not capture (optional)
  \.           '.' 
  [0-9]+       any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more times)
)              end of grouping
 (?=           look ahead to see if there is:
  \s*          whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times)
  lbs          'lbs'
)              end of look-ahead
```

See [`working demo`](https://eval.in/72561)